# Unity error: The property 'RaycastHit.collider' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#

The code:

```
public class interactor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LayerMask interactableLayerMask = 10;
    public interactable inter;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward, out hit, 2, interactableLayerMask)) 
        {
            if (hit.collider.GetComponent<interactable>() != false) 
            {
                if (inter == null || inter.ID != hit.collider<interactable>().ID) 
                {
                    inter = hit.collider.GetComponent<interactable>();
                }
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) 
                {
                    inter.onInteract.Invoke();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class interactable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent onInteract;
    public int ID;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        ID = Random.Range(0,999999);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

This is for an interaction function in a game.

Comment: I assume the error points to this code `hit.collider<interactable>().ID` Compare that to some other code that I assume does not generate an error, like `hit.collider.GetComponent<interactable>()`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: That fixed it. i don't know who you are but i hope you live 100 years and become a billionaire in the next 5 minutes. thank you so much man